# Guys I need help to open a json file from python, but the json is located in another directory

Tags: python, json

I´m running my python file in a directory, let´s say: `/python/python_file.py`

and the json relative is: `/python/python_apps_file/disctionary.json`

and all I need to do is:

```
import json
import random
import os.path

with open(".\python_apps_file\english_dictionary.json","r") as dictionary:
    my_dictionary = list(json.load(dictionary).keys())

print(dictionary[5])
```

I even tried with:

```
with open(os.path.abspath("english_dictionary.json"),"r") as dictionary:
    my_dictionary = list(json.load(dictionary).keys())
```

but still getting the same error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

Comment: Maybe try `print(os.getcwd())` to confirm whether the working directory is what you assume it is?

Comment: What if you use `python...` instead of `.\python...` ?

Comment: "and the json relative is:

/python/python_apps_file/disctionary.json" That's not a relative path, that's an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the filenames are different. It might be a spelling problem.